# SCCM2012 Detection of same version package, if yes stop deploy, if no go on deployment

Tags: sccm, vbscript

We have massive error on SCCM 2012 client when deploying flash 19x, since its last version has auto update ability, many of our clients has already update it before SCCM 2012 deployment. I realize there is a option to detect it while deploy. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ez64gzfchv3sajx/sccm05.png?dl=0

Is there any way to detect it in the package if same version SID package has exist in the pc, no deployment and skip, if no same version is find, please go on.

For some reasons, we cannot use Powershell, I have only VBScrpt and JScript choice, but I did not know how to script, solid example and coding is desired.

Comment: If you are using "Applications" as opposed to "Programs" and you have set up your detection method to work correctly, the SCCM client will just detect that the correct version is already installed and do nothing.  If you don't already have the skills to set up "Applications" correctly and a lab environment to test your work, then unfortunately you're facing a very steep learning curve -- one measured in months, not days or hours.  It's probably better to get a qualified application packager and SCCM admin to help if you need this done fast.

Comment: Alternately, kick off an uninstall before installing the current version.  Or, since it's Flash, and little more than an ad-serving security vulnerability these days, just uninstall it and move on with your life.  (And in response to your last sentence, if you want someone to script stuff for you... hire someone to do it.)